# C# API Project returning Internal Server error first thing in the morning

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, internal-server-error

I have a c# project where the controller is inheriting from ApiController.

It has 1 [HttpPost] method that is used called "Function" where basically it uploads / downloads files through this 1 method.

It works 99% of the time. However, the first call of the day to the web service results in the following exception being thrown from the main project:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

The code that calls the web service is as follows:

```
string jsonResponse;

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);
request.ContentType = "text/json";
request.Method = "POST";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Action = "Get", Filename = filename, id = id });
    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        jsonResponse = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

var file = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(jsonResponse);

return file;
```

It looks like the error is being thrown on the following line:

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I have enabled error logging in the web service to catch any exception, however when I look, there are no exceptions being thrown from the web service. I have tested to check logging works and it does.

Does anyone have any idea's? Could it be a configuration problem with IIS and the application going to sleep?

Any help appreciated

Comment: You can add a logger to your web api and come back with more info. BTW I assume the same happens when you recycle the app in IIS not just "in the morning"

Comment: "I have enabled error logging in the web service to catch any exception, however when I look, there are no exceptions being thrown from the web service. I have tested to check logging works and it does."

Comment: With an exception logger (not IIS logging)? - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling

Comment: yes, nlog exception logger

Comment: Well OK then maybe try something like this - http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

I don't have an experience with it though

Comment: Looks like the logging isn't working correctly on release, so will investigate that first.